# How to load balance EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, server, load-balancing

I have one server with EC2. I want to load balance it. I know i need to create another server with the same contents on it and then set up load balancing for both of them. but with the second server, how can i get the same files on both servers?

what is the most efficient or most used way about doing this?

Comment: Make an AMI of your configured server and add it to an auto-scaling group associated with the load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Any deployment method should take care of this for you.

Salt, ansible, Puppet, chef, opsworks, elastic beanstalk are all there to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the most common way?

Comment: There is no right answer, it's preference. Choose your own that makes sense.

Comment: which way would be the best to scale in the future if your site gets millions or even billions of users a day?

Comment: If you're not sure how to handle the deployment method as-is to load balance you will never reach millions or billions of users per day.

Answer (score 1):

You really should consider using [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) to manage code deployments like this. It is free, and robust.  No need to develop a custom solution, and it has support for deployment hooks to properly manage deployment events eg service validation etc.

This is one of the services AWS provides you to manage code deployments, and it is easy to setup.

If you are using auto scaling groups, it also can be configured to automatically deploy the code when an instance is launched in response to a scaling event.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on your files.

1-Create AMI and start new EC2 with your AMI.

2-Using startup script in your AMI to get latest of your app from git or S3 bucket.